# How to use Reiser4 on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: filesystems, reiserfs

Is there an easy way to use Reiser4 on Debian Wheezy?

I installed reiser4progs but obviously I need a patched Kernel as well to use it. Is there some semi-officially maintained kernel to install somewhere?

Or which alternative filesystems (besides btrfs which I used before - it had severe CPU usage issues) for many small files can I use?

**Edit:** I already found http://kernelnewbies.org/WhyReiser4IsNotIn (this is from 2006 so quite long ago, is it?) and http://sourceforge.net/projects/reiser4/files/reiser4-for-linux-3.x/ already, but I hoped there is a better way.